# vue-router: decoupling data fetching from component

Tags: vuejs2, vue-router

In vue-router, there's a technique for [decoupling components from their routes](https://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/passing-props.html) by using props instead of watching `$route` directly. There's also a technique for [fetching data before route navigation](https://router.vuejs.org/en/advanced/data-fetching.html#fetching-before-navigation).

My issue is that I can't figure out how to combine these two techniques without increasing the coupling between my component and the router. The initial fetch shouldn't be a problem since I could implement the data fetching in the route's `beforeEnter` hook.

However, since vue-router reuses the same component when just the route parameters change, and there's no equivalent to `beforeRouteUpdate` on the route, it seems to me that the only way to react to this is in the component itself, which destroys the nice decoupling with props.

Am I missing some detail that would make this possible?